# How do I start at the first non blank character of a line (Regex)

Tags: regex, editpad

I want Regex to start at the first word/number that isn't blank.  In my example below, I want to start at `LG`. There are lots of other lines of a near identical structure I will also have to match through.

```
    <div class="p13n-sc-truncate p13n-sc-truncated-hyphen p13n-sc-line-clamp-2" aria-hidden="true" data-rows="2" data-truncate-mix-weblab='true'>

        LG 32MA68HY-P 32-Inch IPS Monitor with Display Port and HDMI Inputs
```

My Regex is.. `(?<='True'>\n).*.(?=\n)`

Rather than adding a lot of dots is there a way to start at the first letter/number/word for this line?

I believe `[^\s]` should work but I can't get it working..

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by *start*? Match a line omitting the leading whitespace? You may use `\S.*`. Or, `^\h*\K.*`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes when I say start I mean ommitting the white space and starting at in this case LG. Something like (?<='True'>\n.\S.*).*.(?=\n).  I'll try it out..

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hmm doesn't seem to work.  It's very stubborn.  Are you able to get      LG 32MA68HY-P 32-Inch IPS Monitor with Display Port and HDMI Inputs with no white space at the front?  I can trim through another proecess later but ideally I would of thought this can be done in Regex without that extra step

Comment: Maybe [like this](https://regex101.com/r/IrxDm8/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm using editpadpro atm I'll see if I can't modify that and get it working.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew \k appears to come up as an error when I use that.  It works on that site but not in editpadpro or when I run the job

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew BEAU-TIFUL.  Thanks dude!  I modified my code incorporating what you did.   (?<='true'>\n\s+)\w.*.*(?=\n\s+</div>)

Comment: Looks like in EditPadPro infinite width lookbehind is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EditPadPro](https://www.editpadpro.com/) from JG Software is powered with a regex engine that supports infinite width lookbehind.

You may use a positive lookbehind that makes sure there is a `'true'>` substring followed with a newline and 0+ whitespaces immediately to the left of the current location. Then, you may just consome a non-whitespace char followed with any 0+ chars other than newline.

Here is an example:

```
(?<='true'>\r?\n\s*)\S.*
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%27true%27%3E%5Cs%2B%29%5CS.*&i=%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22p13n-sc-truncate%20p13n-sc-truncated-hyphen%20p13n-sc-line-clamp-2%22%20aria-hidden%3D%22true%22%20data-rows%3D%222%22%20data-truncate-mix-weblab%3D%27true%27%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20LG%2032MA68HY-P%2032-Inch%20IPS%20Monitor%20with%20Display%20Port%20and%20HDMI%20Inputs)

If the char should be a word char, replace `\S` with `\w`.

**Details**:

- `(?<='true'>\r?\n\s*)` - a positive lookbehind that makes sure there is a `'true'>` substring followed with an optional CR and then an LF and 0+ whitespaces immediately to the left of the current location
- `\S` - any non-whitespace char
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than newline as many as possible.